# Is there a way (script ?) to redirect a first visitor of my website to, say welcomepage.html instead of index.html?

Tags: php, html

Hello I'm learning html/css by doing my own website. I'm curious as I want my website to show a different page than index.html for a first time visitor. I know it involve something like cookies and I've seen scripts in similar thread in php, but I don't now where should I put it. I don't know nothing about php, should I put it in a .php page? or Can someone suggest me a ressource to learn to do it comprehensively?

Comment: you can use cookies

Comment: Find a tutorial and ***official*** manuals; read and learn, it's all part of the (coding) fun.

Answer (score 0):

[Cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp) are indeed your way to go.

from w3schools:

> A cookie is often used to identify a user. A cookie is a small file that the server embeds on the user's computer. Each time the same computer requests a page with a browser, it will send the cookie too. With PHP, you can both create and retrieve cookie values.

If you set a cookie when someone visits your website, after that you can then check if the cookie (or a value in your cookie) is set. If it isn't set, they're most likely a new user.

I'd recommend to put the cookie check at the top of your .php page so you redirect the user before any of your html is loaded.

If you've never done anything with PHP before I'd recommend starting with a simple [PHP tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp) first.

Answer (score 0):

Let's play around with cookies!  Basically, when the user firsts visits, we set a a cookie.  Hence you get a "new visitor", after you click `run` again you will see, "Hello, old visitor".  I wrote an example:

```
<?php

if (isset($_COOKIE['visit'])) {
    echo "Hello, old visitor.";
} else {
    echo "new visitor";
    setcookie("visit", true, time() + 5, "/"); //cookie will expire in 5 seconds
}

?>
```